# How do you customize the launching message for Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a Flask app in Cloud9. Whenever I start my Flask app, it says this message:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Is there a way to change this message? I'd like it to say something like this:

```
Connect to me at http://0.0.0.0:80/!
```

I've searched stack overflow and the web but couldn't find anything. I'm starting my app with `app.run()`.
Also, is it possible to make the URL cyan?

Comment: The message [is logged through pythons logging interface on the `INFO`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/09a248649069780b4adfb910fb69f6fb304f2ea3/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L829) level - you should be able to change that level (the `werkzeug` logger) for what gets printed, then output your own message.

Comment: @MatsLindh do you mean I modidy the source code or I change something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change everything besides `Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` by changing `show_server_banner` of `flask.cli`:

```
from flask import Flask
import sys

cli = sys.modules['flask.cli']

# put your own message here
cli.show_server_banner = lambda *x: click.echo("My nice message")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='80')
```

---

To get rid of the `Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ ...` message, you can use `unittest.mock`:

```
from unittest import mock
from werkzeug._internal import _log

def my_startup_log(*args):
    # log all messages except for the * Running on message
    if not args[1].startswith(" * Running on"):
        return _log(*args)

app = Flask(__name__)
with mock.patch('werkzeug.serving._log') as mocked:
    # patch the logger object and replace with own logger
    mocked.side_effect = my_startup_logger
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000')
```

This is very hacky and depends on the internal implementation of flask. Be careful when using this in production code, as this could easily break.

Comment: Nice! Why can't you change that?

Comment: Because it lives in `werkzeug.serving` and is defined in an inner function of `run_simple`. I am not aware of a possibility to change inner functions.

Comment: Would it be possible to make all of `Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` in a different color?

Comment: You could potentially mock the `_log` calls in `werkzeug.serving`. But this would cause all log messages of `app.run` to disappear. is this desired?

Comment: I found a way to filter the messages using `unittest.mock`, updated my answer.

Comment: You can also tell the werkzeug logger that you're not interested in the `info` messages, which is more kosher - get the log with `_log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')` and then change the level, `_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)`. This makes the informal messages on the `info` level disappear. You can also use the logging filter mechanism to make a custom filter that removes anything that starts with ` * Running on`, avoiding any mocking in production code.

Comment: I think the first option doesn't work, since you would also block any other `info` log messages from `app.run`. Do you want me to add the filtering option to my answer?